# "failed to created runc console socket" when calling kubectl exec

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-18.04, microk8s

I have an Ubuntu Server in my basement running [MicroK8S](https://microk8s.io/), installed via Snap. I'm trying to create a simple pod using `kubectl run` that I can exec into for debugging purposes. But I keep failing.

At first, I tried this command:

```
kubectl run -it --rm --restart=Never busybox --image=busybox -- /bin/ash
```

But every time I try to run that, I get this error:

```
pod "busybox deleted"
pod default/busybox terminated (ContainerCannotRun)
failed to create OCI runtime control socket: stat /run/user/0/snap.microk8s: no such file or directory: unknown
```

Then I decided to try and run the container first, and exec into second, as two separate commands. Surprisingly, the initial pod creation actually works, a la this command:

```
kubectl run --image=busybox --restart=Never busybox --image=busybox --command -- tail -f /dev/null
```

But then when I try to exec into it using this command...

```
kubectl exec -it busybox -- /bin/ash
```

...I wind up with this error:

```
failed to create runc console socket: stat /run/user/0/snap.microk8s: no such file or directory: unknown
command terminated with exit code 126
```

Both errors only come into play once I try to connect to a running pod, and both errors reference `/run/user/0/snap.microk8s`. I'm not really sure what those errors mean, though. Is that a problem with my configuration? Or am I missing some dependency? Or is the hard disk corrupt? Or something else entirely? And ultimately: how can I get this working?

Comment: I'm getting exact the same issue with a cluster that used to work. I suspect it's related to me shutting it down and starting it again. Another weird symptom I have is that DNS records like postgres-service.default.svc.cluster.local can no longer be resolved inside the cluster.

Comment: @AlexandruChirițescu I would hope that microk8s is more resilient than dying after a reboot! What do you think will fix this? A full reformat + reinstall maybe? By the way, I also [submitted this as an issue](https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/358) on their Github

Comment: I hope that just removing the snap and installing it again would do the trick. I am running the edge version of microk8s, so I assumed also this version could be a bit more buggy. Thanks for sharing the issue, will be interesting to see if anyone knows the cause. But most likely I will remove/install the snap and deploy all my setup again. Fingers crossed :-)

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide which verion of microk8s you are using.

As you are using kubectl instead of microk8s.kubectl I assume you have created alias.
I have tasted 4 last versions of microk8s 1.11 1.12 1.13 and 1.14. It seems that this issue occurs only in version 1.11.
To check what version you are using currently please execute

```
snap info microk8s
```

Remove old microk8s version

```
sudo snap remove microk8s
```

and install latest version of microk8s

```
sudo snap install microk8s --classic --channel=1.14/stable
```

As additional info, if you need pod which will be in Running state for longer time, you can use nginx image instead of busybox.

```
microk8s.kubectl exec -ti nginx -- /bin/bash
```

If you are new to microk8s very helpful will be this [document](https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s)

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing out old containers and images - this seems to be a docker (not kubernetes) issue caused by lack of space. Some docker [pruning](https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/) can fix that.